# Internatlisation add quote

Tags: thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2 with thymeleaf.

I use internalization in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    $("div.samples-toolbars").html('<div><input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-input" /><label for="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-label">[[#{testDoneInclude}]]</label></div>');

</script>
```

Result is
"Test done include"

don't want to have "

any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the variables into their own statements.  (I think you're confusing the inline JavaScript mechanism when you try and include it in something that's already a string.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    var text = /*[[#{testDoneInclude}]]*/ "";
    $("div.samples-toolbars").html('<div><input type="checkbox" id="testDoneInclude" name="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-input" /><label for="testDoneInclude" class="form-check-label">' + text + '</label></div>');
</script>
```

If something like that doesn't work, you must have the quotes as part of the `testDoneInclude` variable.